# Navigation Timing API implementation in opera and safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, opera, navigation-timing-api

I have to capture the client data about its navigation i.e. the response time of my page and other data parameters which are in Navigation timing API, but i am able to do that only for firefox and chrome. SO can anyone tell me how to get those on Safari and Opera or some alternate mechanism which can be implemented to do so.

Comment: you can also do it in IE10. For Opera - you can manually use dragonfly network profiler, for Safari - no idea - if WebInspector still works there, then just use network inspector, if not - then sorry.

Comment: i don't wanted to do it manually instead i wanted to use JavaScript to capture the data, so how is it possible to do for browsers like opera or safari which does not support this API

Comment: @blackhole did u get a solution if yes can u please share it.

Comment: Apple will include navigation timing API in the next version (8): http://blog.catchpoint.com/2014/07/25/navigation-timing-safari/;

Answer (score 1):

For browsers that don't support the Navigation Timing API, there is the [Boomerang open source project](https://github.com/lognormal/boomerang). This was originally a [yahoo project](https://github.com/yahoo/boomerang) from several years ago but now appears to be maintained by the same person [after he left Yahoo](http://www.lognormal.com/boomerang).

There may be others which provide similar features, but this one appears to have a lot of users over several years and is actively maintained.

As this is a fairly old question, maybe you can also update us with any additional information you've uncovered since then.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a polyfill for it from one of the w3c guys who worked on the spec:
http://nicj.net/usertiming-js/